# Deleting objects in an array built in angular, when a check box is True

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need to loop through a check list and delete the completed items in the array, what i currently have for code is:

```
 app.controller("MainController", ["$scope",function($scope) {
$scope.list = [{
    text: 'Figure your stuff out',
    done: false
  }, {
    text: 'Count to seven',
    done: false
  }


];


$scope.addTask = function() {
  $scope.list.push({
    text: $scope.fromListText,
    done: false
  });
  $scope.fromListText = '';
};
$scope.removeCompleted = function(index) {
  $scope.list.splice(index, 1);

}
```

for my controller, and this as my Html:

```
    <html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-rc.2" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2"        src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-route@*" data-semver="1.4.0-rc.2" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-route.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="toDoList">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Your list brah</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myList" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container">

      <div ng-repeat="task in list">

        <form class = "myTask">
          Task:
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model = "task.done">{{ task.text  }} 
        </form>


      </div>
      <form>
        <input placeHolder="Things I dont want to do..." type="text" ng-  model="fromListText" ng-model-instant/>
        <button class = "myButton" ng-click = addTask() >Add task</button>
      </form>

      <button class = "myButton" ng-click = "removeCompleted()" >Clear Completed Tasks</button>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

I'm a bit new to scripting so all I want to do is have something check to see if the check box is true and if it is then to remove it here is the plunkr link if you want to see the code in action. 
[Plunkr Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/pskVCjDpTiBlkt6b3h3Z?p=preview)

Comment: You  might take a look at the Doc for ngRepeat. There's something like an $index value which can be applied to each item of choice. Than you could remove those items by splice, as you already did.

Answer (score 1):

What you want in your removeCompleted method is

```js
var $scope = {}

$scope.list = [{
    text: 'Figure your stuff out',
    done: true
  }, {
    text: 'Count to seven',
    done: false
  }, {
    text: 'Count to eight',
    done: true
  }, {
    text: 'Count to nine',
    done: false
  }
]

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++) {
     if($scope.list[i].done)  {
      $scope.list.splice(i, 1)
       i--
     }
    }

$scope.list.forEach(function(item) {
  alert(item.text + ', ' + item.done)
})
```

that will loop over your list items and if done is true then it will remove that item out of the array

Comment: This was the closest i got it to work thank you! It seems however that it deletes all of the checked tasks except for the last one that is selected. Would there be any explanation for this? My assumption is that it loops one less time than needed.

Comment: The problem with my previous answer was that the method forEach just loops over all of them but during the looping process the index's were being removed from the array so it could end up removing the wrong index, this new solution takes into account the removing of indexs.

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++) {
     if($scope.list[i].done)  {
      $scope.list.splice(index, 1);
      i--;
     };
    };

Comment: where should this code be place or should it be just in my remove statement?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$scope.deleteTasks = function () {
    for (var i = $scope.tasks.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if ($scope.tasks[i].Completed) {
            $scope.tasks.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

See example [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3z0umx3w/)

Comment: Thank you for the help i got an error in the code that says TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.deleteTasks (http://run.plnkr.co/A1E98UAxh0WCMLht/script.js:31:30)